# Apache Camel: Idempotent SFTP is throwing exception on other node unnecessarily? (Infinispan)

Tags: apache-camel, infinispan, idempotent, camel-ftp

Following is code:

```
    return "sftp://"+getSftpHostName() +getSftpImportDirectory()
            + "?username="+getSftpUserName()
            + "&password="+getSftpPassword() // Stored on wildfly server
            + "&download=true" //Shall be read chunk by chunk to avoid heap space issues. Earlier download=true was used: Harpreet
            + "&useList=true"
            + "&stepwise=false"
            + "&disconnect=true"
            + "&passiveMode=true"
            + "&reconnectDelay=10000"
            + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true"
            + "&delay="+getSftpDelay()
            + "&include="+ getSftpFileName()
            + "&preMove=$simple{file:onlyname}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.processing"
            + "&move="+getSftpSuccessDirectory()+"$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.success"
            + "&moveFailed="+getSftpFailedDirectory()+"$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.failed"
            + "&readLock=idempotent-changed"
            + "&idempotentRepository=#infinispan"
            + "&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true";
```

We have three nodes. This locks file on Node 1 and route starts all logs printed but on Node 2 it shows following exception only (Node 3 is fine):

```
Cannot rename file from: Hrm/test/From_HRM/import/Integrator_2.xml to: Hrm/test/From_HRM/import/Integrator_2.xml.2020-05-07T01-27-19.processing, StackTrace: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot rename file from: Hrm/test/From_HRM/import/Integrator_2.xml to: Hrm/test/From_HRM/import/Integrator_2.xml.2020-05-07T01-27-19.processing
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.renameFile(SftpOperations.java:467)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:113)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.begin(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:45)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:360)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:137)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:219)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:183)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 2: No such file
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rename(ChannelSftp.java:1950)
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.renameFile(SftpOperations.java:463)
```

Why node 2 even trying to try that file? (Not able to understand what changes shall i do?)

(A small issue we face once a month i.e file gets loss and above error appears on all three nodes. If anyone can comment on same that would be help too)

**Updated INfinispan Settings**:

```
public class InfinispanIdempodentRepositoryProducer {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/camel")
    private CacheContainer container;

    @Produces
    @Named("infinispan")
    public InfinispanIdempotentRepository createInfinispanInfinispanIdempotentRepository() {
        return new InfinispanIdempotentRepository(container, "camel-default-cache");
    }

}


 ***Configuration***
The configuration of an infinispan cache container

Aliases

Default Cache: camel-default-cache

Module: org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan

Statistics Enabled: false

***Async Operations***
Defines a thread pool used for asynchronous operations.

Keepalive Time: 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 25

Min Threads: 25

Queue Length: 1000

***Expiration***
Defines a thread pool used for for evictions.


Keepalive Time: 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 1

***Listener***
Defines a thread pool used for asynchronous cache listener notifications.

Keepalive Time: 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 1

Min Threads: 1

Queue Length: 100000

***Persistence***
Defines a thread pool used for interacting with the persistent store.


Keepalive Time: 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 4

***Remote Command***
Defines a thread pool used to execute remote commands.

Keepalive Time 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 200

Min Threads:  1

Queue Length: 0

***State Transfer***
Defines a thread pool used for for state transfer.

Keepalive Time: 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 60

Min Threads: 1

Queue Length: 0

***Transport***
Defines a thread pool used for asynchronous transport communication.

Keepalive Time: 60000MILLISECONDS

Max Threads: 25

Min Threads: 25

Queue Length: 100000

***JGroups***
The description of the transport used by this cache container

Channel: ee

Lock Timeout: 240000MILLISECONDS
```

More Settings in replicated cache:

```
***Locking***

Acquire Timeout:15000MILLISECONDS

Concurrency Level:1000

Isolation:READ_COMMITTED

Striping:false

***Partition Handling***

Enabled:false

***State TRansfer***

Chunk Size:512

Timeout:240000MILLISECONDS

***TRansaction***

Locking:OPTIMISTIC

Mode:FULL_XA

Stop Timeout:10000MILLISECONDS


***Expiration***

Interval:60000MILLISECONDS

Lifespan:-1MILLISECONDS

Max Idle:-1MILLISECONDS

***Attributes***

Module:

Remote Timeout:17500MILLISECONDS

Statistics Enabled:false


***Memory***
Size:-1
```

Comment: You would need to check your infinispan configuration. Can you share `infinispan-subsystem` definition and `#infinispan` bean declaration?

Comment: @Bedla: I have added whole infinispan setting and code in description. Could you please look into it and assist. I shall be thankful.